# Can we publish Power BI files into Private cloud (other than azure)?

Tags: powerbi

We have in house project which we are developing in our cloud environment.

So we wanted to use PowerBi as the visualization tool. So can you please suggest if we can publish PowerBi files into our Cloud environment other than azure.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is [coming](https://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/on-premise-power-bi-a-microsoft-story/) to some degree in SQL Server Reporting Services vNext.